# Dialog on PrimeFaces does not update and calculate date difference

Tags: ajax, date, primefaces

Dialog on PrimeFaces does not update and calculate date difference in my dialog page.

Dialog page:

```
        <p:dialog id="GrupoCreateDlg" widgetVar="GrupoCreateDialog" modal="true" resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" header="#{bundle.CreateGrupoTitle}">
        <h:form id="GrupoCreateForm">
            <h:panelGroup id="display">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{grupoController.selected != null}">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGrupoLabel_grupo}" for="grupo" />
                    <p:inputText id="grupo" value="#{grupoController.selected.grupo}" title="#{bundle.CreateGrupoTitle_grupo}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateGrupoRequiredMessage_grupo}"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGrupoLabel_usuario}" for="usuario" />
                    <p:inputText id="usuario" value="#{grupoController.selected.usuario}" title="#{bundle.CreateGrupoTitle_usuario}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateGrupoRequiredMessage_usuario}"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGrupoLabel_clave}" for="clave" />
                    <p:inputText id="clave" value="#{grupoController.selected.clave}" title="#{bundle.CreateGrupoTitle_clave}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateGrupoRequiredMessage_clave}"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGrupoLabel_detalle}" for="detalle" />
                    <p:inputText id="detalle" value="#{grupoController.selected.detalle}" title="#{bundle.CreateGrupoTitle_detalle}" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGrupoLabel_fechainicio}" for="fechainicio" />
                    <p:calendar id="fechainicio" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{grupoController.selected.fechainicio}" title="#{bundle.EditGrupoTitle_fechainicio}"
                                locale="es" showOn="button" showButtonPanel="true"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGrupoLabel_fechafin}" for="fechafin" />
                    <p:calendar id="fechafin" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{grupoController.selected.fechafin}" title="#{bundle.EditGrupoTitle_fechafin}"
                                locale="es" showOn="button" showButtonPanel="true">
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="dias"/>
                    </p:calendar>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Dias"/>
                    <h:outputText id="dias" value="#{grupoController.calcularFechas()}">
                        <f:convertNumber type="number"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGrupoLabel_incidencia}" for="incidencia" />
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="incidencia" value="#{grupoController.selected.incidencia}" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGrupoLabel_fechaincidencia}" for="fechaincidencia" />
                    <p:calendar id="fechaincidencia" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{grupoController.selected.fechaincidencia}" title="#{bundle.EditGrupoTitle_fechaincidencia}"
                                locale="es" showOn="button" showButtonPanel="true"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGrupoLabel_fechaavisocaducidad}" for="fechaavisocaducidad" />
                    <p:calendar id="fechaavisocaducidad" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" value="#{grupoController.selected.fechaavisocaducidad}" title="#{bundle.EditGrupoTitle_fechaavisocaducidad}"
                                locale="es" showOn="button" showButtonPanel="true"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{grupoController.create}" value="#{bundle.Save}" update="display,:GrupoListForm:datalist,:growl" oncomplete="handleSubmit(args,'GrupoCreateDialog');"/>
                <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Cancel}" onclick="GrupoCreateDialog.hide()"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

Groupo controller:

```
    public int calcularFechas() throws ParseException {
    diasDuracion = 0;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date fechaFinal = selected.getFechainicio();
        Date fechaInicial = selected.getFechainicio();

        diasDuracion = (int) ((fechaFinal.getTime() - fechaInicial.getTime()) / 86400000);

        System.out.println("Hay " + diasDuracion + " dias de diferencia");

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return diasDuracion;

}
```

The HTML must be show the difference between date initial and finish (on days) in the outputText.
What's wrong?
The outputText **dias** must be update without close the dialog page.

Answer (score 0):

I copy and paste your stuff into my project and edit it like that:

Put the calcularFechas() into

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="dias" listener="#{grupoController.calcularFechas()"/>
```

and write a method

`getCalcularFechas(){ ...
}`

It worked for me like that because the listener was called after the event was fired.

Comment: What? Really ? I try it but I meet with the NullPoint ever time Grave:   java.lang.NullPointerException
 at servicio.controller.GrupoController.getCalcularFechas(GrupoController.java:168) --> at this line:             diasDuracion = (int) ((fechaFinal.getTime() - fechaInicial.getTime()) / 86400000);